# Cartesian product as a result of inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cartesian

I have two tables:actors and movies, and a third table role, which connects them. 
ActorId is the primary key for actors. MovieCode is the primary key for the movies table. I have a page of an actor where I need to show the date when the movie was published, the name of the movie and the role of the actor.
My query is:

```
SELECT mo.date, mo.title, role.roleDescription
FROM movies mo, role
inner join actors
on role.actorId=actors.actorId
inner join movies 
on role.movieCode=movies.movieCode
where role.actorid=2
```

The query returns me the Cartesian product. What could be the problem?Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one ,since you want to select the movies and roles of actor for a specific actor you can skip the join on actor table, also in your query you are joining movies two times

```
SELECT mo.date, mo.title, r.roleDescription
FROM movies mo, 
INNER JOIN role r
ON r.movieCode=mo.movieCode
WHERE r.actorid=2
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're joining to `movies` twice: once as `mo`, and once as `movies`. `mo` is never mentioned in any `ON` clause or `WHERE` clause, so you never filter out any of the values of `mo`. To fix it, just remove the `movies mo,` part, and change the fields in your `SELECT`-list to use `movies` instead of `mo`:

```
SELECT movies.date, movies.title, role.roleDescription
FROM role
inner join actors
on role.actorId=actors.actorId
inner join movies 
on role.movieCode=movies.movieCode
where role.actorid=2
```

Also, you don't really need the join to `actors`, since you're not selecting anything from `actors` and you already know what value of `actorid` you want. So removing that, and restructuring a bit for clarity:

```
SELECT movies.date,
       movies.title,
       role.roleDescription
  FROM movies
  JOIN role
    ON role.movieCode = movies.movieCode
 WHERE role.actorid = 2
;
```